# (Recursively) build a dictionary from a list of lists, and then know how deep down it is.

Tags: python, recursion, nested

I have a series of nodes like:

```
nodes = [['mid2', 'top1'],
 ['low2', 'mid2'],
 ['mid3', 'top2'],
 ['low1', 'mid1'],
 ['top1', None],
 ['top2', None],
 ['low3', 'mid3'],
 ['mid1', 'top1']]
```

They need to look like this:

```
desired_result = {
    "top1": {
        "mid1": {
            "low1": {}
        },
        "mid2": {
            "low2": {}
        }
    },
    "top2": {
        "mid3": {
            "low3": {}
        }
    }
}
```

Since each item in the list is only 2 elements, I'm having trouble building the tree from scratch. I can build the first 2 levels, but then adding the 3rd (or in future, 4th tier nodes is really hard.

Also, at the end, I need to be able to find out how many levels deep a node is in the tree. Is the best way to do this by simply iterating through the tree and making an index or can it be done arbitrarily?

Comment: What did you write?

Answer (score 0):

That was an interesting problem, so I wrote some code even if you didn't provide any :

```
from collections import defaultdict

nodes_with_children = defaultdict(list)

nodes = [['mid2', 'top1'],
         ['low2', 'mid2'],
         ['mid3', 'top2'],
         ['low1', 'mid1'],
         ['top1', None],
         ['top2', None],
         ['low3', 'mid3'],
         ['mid1', 'top1']]

for child, parent in nodes:
    nodes_with_children[parent].append(child)

print nodes_with_children
# defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'top2': ['mid3'], 'top1': ['mid2', 'mid1'],
# None: ['top1', 'top2'], 'mid2': ['low2'], 'mid3': ['low3'], 'mid1':
# ['low1']})


def build_tree(parent=None):
    children = nodes_with_children.get(parent, {})
    return {node: build_tree(node) for node in children}


print build_tree()

# {
#   'top2': {
#     'mid3': {
#       'low3': {
#       }
#     }
#   },
#   'top1': {
#     'mid2': {
#       'low2': {
#       }
#     },
#     'mid1': {
#       'low1': {
#       }
#     }
#   }
# }
```

There's really not much left to do to get the tree depth. You could do it directly inside `build_tree()`.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is quite similar to @Eric's, but nonetheless I'll publish it:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint


def make_tree(name2kids, name=None):
    return {kid: make_tree(name2kids, kid)
            for kid in name2kids[name]}


def find_depth(tree):
    if not tree:
        return 0
    return 1 + max(find_depth(subtree) for subtree in tree.values())


def main():
    """
    >>> main()
    {'top1': {'mid1': {'low1': {}}, 'mid2': {'low2': {}}},
     'top2': {'mid3': {'low3': {}}}}
    depth = 3
    """
    nodes = [['mid2', 'top1'],
             ['low2', 'mid2'],
             ['mid3', 'top2'],
             ['low1', 'mid1'],
             ['top1', None],
             ['top2', None],
             ['low3', 'mid3'],
             ['mid1', 'top1']]

    name2kids = defaultdict(list)
    for kid, name in nodes:
        name2kids[name].append(kid)

    tree = make_tree(name2kids)
    pprint(tree)

    depth = find_depth(tree)
    print('depth = {}'.format(depth))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

(Run: `python -m doctest script.py --verbose`).